# Adding decimals from a list of interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, foreach, return

Hello friends,

```
    public decimal Balance
    {
        get 
        {
            _test = 0m;
            foreach (ITransaction t in _Transactions)
            {
                _test += t.Value;
            }
            return _OpeningBalance + _test;
        }
    }
```

The Value variable of ITransaction and the _OpeningBalance instance variable are both decimals. Is there a shorter way to return the sum of the ITransaction values and the _OpeningBalance without using a 'temporary variable'? This is for a university assignment and I want the code to be as neat as possible. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try LINQ `Sum()`

```
return _OpeningBalance + _Transactions.Sum(t => t.Value);
```

You can find an example along with documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/bb534734%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).